# Update PowerPoint 2016 to 2019

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am using a Windows 10 Asus laptop and I have a Microsoft 365 subscription. I want to update from the 2016 version to the 2019 version, But when I go the account settings of powerpoint and check for updates it says that I have the latest version of MS Office installed.

[This is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Tye.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to install the office 365 packages. They are different from the 2016 and 2019 packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows “Microsoft Office Home and Student 2016” is activated.

This product is NOT Microsoft 365. It is the “one-time” purchase version. If you want the latest version you will need to make a one-time purchase of a newer version of [Office Home and Student](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/office-home-student-2021/cfq7ttc0h8n8?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) or purchase a [Microsoft 365 subscription](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/buy/compare-all-microsoft-365-products-b) which always provides the latest updates.

If you have a valid Microsoft 365 subscription, you will need to uninstall the version of Office you currently have installed, then [login to your Microsoft account and download the Office 365 subscription version and install it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-microsoft-365-or-office-2021-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658).